# ng-repeat repeating elements but not showing content inside ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a controller:

```
function ItemsController($scope, $http){
    $scope.init = function(){
        $scope.siteItems = [
            {id:'1', path:'img/1.png'},
            {id:'2', path:'img/2.png'}
        ];
    }
};
```

and I have a view items.html:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="ItemsController" ng-init="init()">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3" ng-repeat="item in siteItems">
    <a href="#/item/{{item.id}}" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="{{item.path}}">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

when ever I load the view inside the ng-view the list gets initialised and ng-repeat produces two elements. However {{item.path}} and {{item.id}} are empty. I tried to do it with ng-src but the result was the same. I was curious if it will work with ng-bind just to see if it will bind the content and it works but its not what Im trying to do. When ever I move the content from the items.html to the main index.html view everything works. Does anybody have an idea what am I doing wrong?

**EDITED:**

Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZNAqzJElitO5aXqZrVPi?p=preview). On my machine I wrote it like:

[image]

and I get a result of:
[image]

Comment: well in your ng-repeat you reference siteImages, but you set up siteItems in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

I landed this on this probably 2 years late, but I was using Jekyll and although it's strange that the source code look exactly the same, meaning it should work, it doesn't.

The reason being `{{ }}` is being reserved for Liquid template engine. To overcome this, I have found this code to *re-define* the syntax.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});
```

So now I can use `[[ ]]` instead of `{{ }}` and it works out.

Source: http://www.noxidsoft.com/development/using-jekyll-and-angularjs-together/

Comment: The same thing. Current project works on Node.JS + Swig views. Problem was solved by wrapping ng-repeat blocks in raw-blocks.
   `{% raw %}
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
    {% endraw %}`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing it like this:

```
function ItemsController($scope, $http){
    $scope.items = [
        {id:'1', path:'img/1.png'},
        {id:'2', path:'img/2.png'}
    ];  
};
```

And the Html without the init?

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="ItemsController">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <a href="#/item/{{item.id}}" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="{{item.path}}">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I have and the result is exactly the same.

Comment: From the Angular page on ngInit: "The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope." So I think this is the "right" approach even if it doesn't yet yield the results you need.

Answer (score 0):

I made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/y1dDizA0GjXZHeQyDoQb?p=preview) out of mylescc's answer, and it's working fine:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="ItemsController">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <a href="#/item/{{item.id}}" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="{{item.path}}">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is no picture at there referenced path, of course, but the href link is shown correctly. And actually your code works fine, too. See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oVDVbbebKmpjmPMMSB8W?p=preview). So, it seems to me, you haven't initialized angularjs correctly.

Comment: In my case the html that you wrote is in a separate file and I am biding the ng-view with it ... as I said if I put it in the main html file like you did it works.

Comment: @user1. Why don't you produce a plunker or jsfiddle with the sample, it would be much easier to see what's wrong with your code.

Comment: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZNAqzJElitO5aXqZrVPi?p=preview)
Here is a plunker. The strange thing is that its working

Comment: I thought that producing a plunker by yourself would direct you in the right direction. So now you are sure you know how to do it, and there is surely some problem in your original code (missing reference, order of loading javascript files or something completely different). You know where to search from here on ...

Comment: Thanks but its not helping. I edited the post to show the result I get.

Comment: Obviously you get two items back from your backend. Also, they don't seem to be of the correct type. What are you using as your backend api: PHP, .NET, JAVA or something else? I guess the result returned from the backend is not in the correct format.

Comment: At the example Im not making a request to the backend at all as you see: $scope.init = function(){
        $scope.siteItems = [
            {id:'1', path:'img/1.png'},
            {id:'2', path:'img/2.png'}
        ];
    }

Comment: I thought this was a simplified version of a more complex real application. But this can't be the exact application you have, because then it would work. As I said, you obviously get two items back, but they are not of type item with the propeties id and path. I can reproduce your error if I misspell id with xid and path with xpath in my html. See plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Pd5IHp5vhbyVQJZBqd7n?p=preview

Comment: It is a simplified version yes. Its not the whole project.But the example that I wrote is the exactly the same in my code.And nothing is misspelled. Thanks for trying to help.